# Gradle not maintaining directory hierarchy on gradle build

Tags: java, spring, gradle, groovy, build

I am starting a project using gradle to build it. The folder structure follows:

```
java_data_structures
├── build.gradle
├── build
|   ├── classes
|   |   ├── groovy
|   |   |   └── test
|   |   |       └── DoublyLinkedListSpec.class
|   |   └── java
|   |       └── main
|   |           ├── Application.class
|   |           └── DoublyLinkedList.class
|   ├── distributions
|   └── other
|
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── Application.java
    │       ├── graphs
    │       ├── maps
    │       ├── matricies
    │       ├── sets
    │       ├── trees
    │       ├── vectors
    │       |   └── DoublyLinkedList.java
    │       └── Application.java  
    └── test
        └── groovy
            └── vectors
                └── DoublyLinkedListSpec.groovy
```

The issue is that, the folder structure in the `build/classes/java` and `build/classes/groovy` have been changed. It just lumps all of the class files into one folder - `main` and `tests` respectively. This is an issue for me because in my `Application.java` file, I have the following code:

```
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list;
    Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3};

    list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>(array);

    System.out.println(list);

  }
}
```

I am able to access the `DoublyLinkedList` without using an `import` statement. I would like for my code to look like this:

```
import vectors.DoublyLinkedList;

public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list;
    Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3};

    list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>(array);

    System.out.println(list);

  }
}
```

But, when I run `gradle build` with the above code, I get the following error:

```
> Task :compileJava
/Users/jod/java_data_structures/src/main/java/Application.java:1: error: package vectors does not exist
import vectors.DoublyLinkedList;
              ^
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

This is to be expected, as the structure of the `build/classes/java/main` folder has all the class files adjacent to each other without their respective folders. My `gradle.build` file follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = "Application"

jar {
  baseName = 'java_data_structures'
  version = '0.0.1'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile(
    'junit:junit:4.12',
    'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4',
    'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4',
    'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.1.RELEASE',
    'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'
  )
}

javadoc {
  destinationDir = new File("${projectDir}/doc/javadoc")
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  classpath = configurations.compile
}
```

What do I need to do such that my folder hierarchy maintains the same? This is the structure I would like:

```
java_data_structures
├── build.gradle
├── build
|   ├── classes
|   |   ├── groovy
|   |   |   └── test
|   |   |       └── vectors
|   |   |           └── DoublyLinkedList.class
|   |   └── java
|   |       └── main
|   |           ├── Application.class
|   |           └── vectors
|   |               └── DoublyLinkedList.class
|   ├── distributions
|   └── other
|
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── Application.java
    │       ├── graphs
    │       ├── maps
    │       ├── matricies
    │       ├── sets
    │       ├── trees
    │       ├── vectors
    │       |   └── DoublyLinkedList.java
    │       └── Application.java  
    └── test
        └── groovy
            └── vectors
                └── DoublyLinkedListSpec.groovy
```

Comment: Please show the header of `DoublyLinkedList`, that is everything up to the class declaration line.

Comment: Hey, I actually realized yesterday, that that was the problem. I did not have the `package vectors;` line at the top. As soon as I added the `package` lines to each file, it worked as expected. I overlooked the small detail, as I was writing this in Atom (no IDE), and I forgot to type it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as indicated in the comments on the question, the issue was a missing `package vectors;` in the `DoublyLinkedList.java` file.